# Dropdown not showing values on load

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a dropdown in my component.html that needs to be populated with values when the user clicks an edit button. Now all the values, including that of the dropdown are being retrieved but the dropdown is the only control that the user has to click in order to see the values. I want the dropdown to show the value without the user clicking it.

Here's the code for the component.html,

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Completed" formControlName="completed" #completed>
        <mat-option value="true">Yes</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="false">No</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

And here's the code for my edit component class,

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {

        this.id = parseInt(params.id);
        this.blogService.getBooksById(this.id).subscribe(res => {
            this.book = res;
            this.completed = this.book[0].completed;

            if (this.book[0].completed == true)
                this.completed = "Yes"
            else
                this.completed = "No"

            this.updateForm.get('title').setValue(this.book[0].title);
            this.updateForm.get('comments').setValue(this.book[0].comments);
            this.updateForm.get('completed').setValue(this.completed);
        });
    });
}
```

So there are no errors. I am able to edit and save. But I do not want the user to click the dropdown to see what the values are. The dropdown should show the value of `completed` for the corresponding book as retrieved from the form. The `updateForm` is of type `FormGroup`. Thank you.

Comment: Your possible values are the string "Yes" and string "No", so in your options your value must be value="Yes" and value="No"

Comment: Thank you @Eliseo. I changed that and then i went on to add a function that converts the "Yes" to true and "No" to false as i have a boolean datatype for the field in the database

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `this.completed` to "true" or "false" instead of "yes" or "no"
because this is the value of your `mat-otion`

the code should look as following:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {

        this.id = parseInt(params.id);
        this.blogService.getBooksById(this.id).subscribe(res => {
            this.book = res;
            this.completed = this.book[0].completed;

            if (this.book[0].completed == true)
                this.completed = "true"
            else
                this.completed = "false"

            this.updateForm.get('title').setValue(this.book[0].title);
            this.updateForm.get('comments').setValue(this.book[0].comments);
            this.updateForm.get('completed').setValue(this.completed);
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding to our question, just update template file as:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Completed" [(ngModel)]="completed" #completed>
        <mat-option value="true">Yes</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="false">No</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

And remove `this.updateForm.get('completed').setValue(this.completed);` line from your ts file.

As I have no Source for any external API data, I have created a demo [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ldzadc?file=app%2Fselect-overview-example.html)

Please let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Thank you Sanket. SoI gave it a try but I am getting an error stating that `Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-select'.`

Comment: Have you imported `FormsModule` into your module.ts file?

Comment: I imported FormsModule then i got another error `ngModel cannot be used to register form controls with a parent formGroup directive.  Try using
      formGroup's partner directive "formControlName" instead.` Looks like it needs a bit of tinkering with the current code. I will stick to the current solution for now and maybe get back to this later on. Thanks again Sanket.

Comment: Can you please send me link to our code over stackBlitz?